# Having Trouble Initializing Postgresql Database Through PG-Promise

Tags: postgresql, typescript, pg-promise

I'm completely new to Express/Postgresql and I'm trying to learn them to create a web application. After some poking around, I decided that I wanted to develop my back-end with TypeScript. I successfully converted all my other files from JavaScript to TypeScript, but I still can't figure out how to initialize the pg-promise connection in TypeScript!

I've been trying to follow the TypeScript guidelines in this link here. https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/typescript

```
// Initialize the PostGres database conneciton for use throughout 
the entire application
import {IMain, IDatabase} from 'pg-promise';
import * as pgPromise from 'pg-promise';

const pgp: IMain = pgPromise({
    query(e: any) {
        console.log('QUERY RESULT:', e.query);
    },
    receive(data: any, result: any, e: any) {
        console.log(`DATA FROM QUERY ${e.query} WAS RECEIVED.`);
    }
});

const connection: any = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    database: 'RushHub',
    user: 'RyanArifin',
    password: null
}
const db: IDatabase<any> = pgp(connection);
export {
    db
};
```

I currently am getting the error "TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'typeof pgPromise' has no compatible call signatures." This error is coming from when I try to set my initialization options. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use [pg-promise-demo](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise-demo) as reference, because it works fine there.

Comment: Thanks! I was actually looking at that as well, and I was wondering how I could initialize the database without the "IExtensions" interface (or is it required for this to work)? The reason I ask is because the "IExtension", from what I understand, just extends the "UsersRepository" and "ProductsRepository" extensions, which I won't need in my smaller program (as of right now). Is there a way to create the initialization options without the IExtension interface? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the problem. Apparently in Javascript ES6, you need to use "import pgPromise from 'pg-promise'" instead of "import * as pgPromise from 'pg-promise';".

Answer (score 5):

This is standard TypeScript configuration flag - `esModuleInterop`. When set to true, the import syntax is `import pgPromise from 'pg-promise';`, and when `false`, which is the default, the syntax is `import * as pgPromise from 'pg-promise';`.

The library gives you example for the default TypeScript configuration.